# Search value in MS Access from textbox

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to get record from my table in Access against the value i have entered in my Form

I have a form with a textbox and a button ,on button press it executes a query

query is :

```
                SELECT *FROM Items WHERE (((Items.ItemName)=lmap));
```

but i want to get only those items which name i entered in my textbox ,for that what should i write instead of lamp,

my textbox name is text1

i tried

```
                 SELECT *FROM Items WHERE (((Items.ItemName)=&text1));
```

but its not working

any suggestions 
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM Items WHERE ItemName=[Forms]![MyOpenFormName]![Text1]
```

Referencing the name in brackets should work.

Comment: thanks  , this method brings up a textbox window asking to enter the item name , but i dont want that window , i need to get the items whose name i already entered in that form's text box

Comment: a textbox usually appears when access can't interpret the name. Is your textbox really called Text1?

Comment: YES ITS TEXT1, Its appearing when i open form design view and then if i click on text box then on the right in property sheet it says Name : text1.  if i entered in my textbox e.g  lamps   and in that textbox window which appears i enter bags , result shows for bags not for lamps  , thats the problem

Comment: @cularis You cannot use Me in a query in that way, it is only available in VBA and only outside the quotes: `s="SELECT * FROM Items WHERE ItemName='" & Me.Text1 & "'"`, nor can you simply refer to Text1, you must supply the full reference `SELECT * FROM Items WHERE ItemName=Forms!MyOpenFormName!Text1`

Comment: @Remou, tried deleting the answer but it doesn't work as it is accepted already.

Comment: @cularis You may wish to edit for the next reader and to avoid possible future down votes :)